# I am in need of connecting to DB2 AS/400 database from Oracle Apex.

Tags: db2, oracle-apex

Is there any feasibility from Oracle to have a connection established to DB2 database so that I can query on DB2 database and generate reports from Oracle Apex?
OR
Is it possible to create a View in Oracle from a remote DB2 database?
OR
What options do i have in order to develop reports in Oracle Apex from the data i have in DB2 database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I know, this is an old question and you've already found a workaround. Anyway,) the keyword you might be interested in is **gateway**. This is Oracle 10g [Database Gateway for DB2/400 Installation and User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b16222/intro.htm#i26786). I don't know which database you use, but - if 10g is not the one, I hope you'll manage to find the right documentation.

Shortly: after installing the gateway between Oracle and DB2, you'd create a **database link**. Then, in your Oracle schema, create a **view** that selects data over that database link from DB2 database. Finally, fetch data in Apex from the view.

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot for your valuable suggestion.  I will explore more on this and update my comments again.  Thanks for your time again.

Answer (score 0):

As i didn't find a way to directly connect to DB2 from Oracle PL/SQL, i used a work-around.  As this is a reporting tool, we are ok to have this tool running with the data which is 1 day off, we did the following:

1) Extract the data required from DB2 database to CSV files.  We used a DB2 command which can be run at command line to extract the data into a CSV 
2) Then we imported the data into Oracle tables using sqlldr